# Why is this Recursion not getting its base case?

Tags: c++, recursion, mergesort

I am trying to implement a merge sort function. Here is my code:

```
void
merge_sort(int a[], int l, int u)
{
  int mid = (l + u) / 2;
  if (mid) {
    merge_sort(a, l, mid);
    merge_sort(a, mid + 1, u);
    merge(a, l, mid, u);
  }
}
```

I checked that `mid` gets value `0` but then again gets its initial value and Turns into an infinite loop.

Comment: Please see [mcve]. Your question should always include example data, and expected vs actual output.

Comment: @LYRICSAREAWESOME: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score

Answer (score 2):

What you are supposed to check is

```
if (mid != l) {
    // ...
}
```

See a complete merge sort implementation [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rwCDBG).

**Edit** This assumes `u` is not in the range of elements that are meant to be sorted. If it is, you should test`if (l < u)`.

Comment: The OP seems to assume that `u` is included in the range, so the proper test is `if (l < u)`, not `if (mid != l)` which would fail to sort 2 element chunks.

Comment: @chqrlie thank you for the feed back. Added that to the answer.

Comment: if `u` is not in the range to be sorted, the second recursive call `merge_sort(a, mid + 1, u);` is incorrect, it should be `merge_sort(a, mid, u);`

Comment: @chqrlie that's why I initially added an example implementation to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must check if the range has at least 2 elements:

```c
/* sort a range of elements from `l` to `u` inclusively */
void merge_sort(int a[], int l, int u) {
    if (l < u) {
        int mid = l + (u - l) / 2;
        merge_sort(a, l, mid);
        merge_sort(a, mid + 1, u);
        merge(a, l, mid, u);
    }
}
```

If the upper bound `u` is not included in the range, the code should be changed to:

```c
/* sort a range of elements from `l` included to `u` excluded */
void merge_sort(int a[], int l, int u) {
    if (u - l >= 2) {
        int mid = l + (u - l) / 2;
        merge_sort(a, l, mid);
        merge_sort(a, mid, u);
        merge(a, l, mid, u);
    }
}
```